# Python Newbie Having Trouble With A TCP Client

Tags: python, tcp, byte, typeerror

Basically I'm just starting out with python networking and python in general and I can't get my TCP client to send data. It says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 14, in <module>
    client.send(data) #this is where I get the error
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

The code is as follows:

```
import socket

target_host = "www.google.com"
target_port = 80 

#create socket object
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

#connect the client
client.connect((target_host,target_port))

#send some data
data = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: google.com\r\n\r\n"
client.send(data) #this is where I get the error

#receive some data
response = client.recv(4096)

print(response)
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Whats the traceback you are getting?

Comment: 4096 is not a string

Comment: You are using python3.x use python2.x and it will work

Comment: You can also use `client.send(data.encode('utf-8'))` rather than `client.send(data)`

Comment: thanks everyone I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably using Python 3.X. [`socket.send()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/socket.html#socket.socket.send) expected a bytes type argument but `data` is an unicode string. You must encode the string using [`str.encode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) method. Similarly you would use [`bytes.decode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode) to receive the data:

```
import socket

target_host = "www.google.com"
target_port = 80

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect((target_host,target_port))

data = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: google.com\r\n\r\n"
client.send(data.encode('utf-8'))

response = client.recv(4096).decode('utf-8')

print(response)
```

Comment: Thanks. You fixed my encoding error but the receive code now gives me a syntax error. It isn't apparent to me where the error is, I have the same code you have.

Comment: @tjwilkins I have tested my code and its  run without errors in Python 3.5.2 and Python 2.7.12. Copy and paste all my code and try, i can't reproduce your error.

Comment: I'll be damned, yours works. Perhaps I have an error with mixing spaces and indents but I don't think so. I'll just rewrite my code from scratch. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python2.x your code is correct. As in the documentation for  python2 [`socket.send()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.send) takes a string parameter. But if you are using python3.x you can see that [`socket.send()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/socket.html#socket.socket.send) takes a bytes parameter. Thus you have to convert your string `data` into bytes using [`str.encode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode). So your code might look like this instead.

```
import socket

target_host = "www.google.com"
target_port = 80 

#create socket object
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

#connect the client
client.connect((target_host,target_port))

#send some data
data = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: google.com\r\n\r\n"
client.send(data.encode('utf-8'))

#receive some data
response = client.recv(4096)

print(response)
```

Comment: I used the code you suggested and it works but now I get a syntax error in the receive code.

Comment: data = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: google.com\r\n\r\n"
    client.send(data.encode(('utf-8')) #  <--- This is where I changed the     code

    #receive some data
    response = client.recv(4096).decode('utf-8')       <--- I get a  syntax_error here
    print(response)

Answer (score 0):

So I encoded the data with utf-8 as was suggested by a few people and rewrote my code which fixed the odd syntax error. Now my code works perfectly. Thank you to everyone who posted but especially to @FJSevilla. The working code is as follows:

```
import socket

target_host = "www.google.com"
target_port = 80

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect((target_host,target_port))

data = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: google.com\r\n\r\n"
client.send(data.encode('utf-8'))

response = client.recv(4096).decode('utf-8')

print(response)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion using Python 3.7 is to add the letter "b" in the message. For example:

```
s.send(b"GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: google.com\r\n\r\n")
```

```
import socket

t_host = "www.google.com"
t_port = 80

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.connect((t_host, t_port))

s.send(b"GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: google.com\r\n\r\n")

response = s.recv(4096)

print(response)
```